# Get max value field from multiple collections in the same format from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongojs

In mongodb, I have multiple collections which have similar data structure.

```
collectionA
{
    ...
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: Date
}

collectionB
    {
    ...
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: Date
}
```

I need to be able to get the last updated document from these two collections (could be more collections)

Is it possible to do this in a single query? I don't want to get latest updated doc from each collection and then compare results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, MongoDB queries can only target a single collection.

You'll need to separately query all collections (concurrently for best performance) and then merge the results manually.